# python: Finding a index in one list and then replacing second list with the item from a index in first list

Tags: python, arrays, list, replace

I am currently trying to find a item in a list, take it's position and find that same position in another list to replace it with the item in the first list.

example:

```py
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c' ]

list_2 = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
```

I would try to find `'a'`, take it's index, find the index in the second list and replace that item in that index. So the ones become `'a'` in `list_2`

Comment: This is a pretty trivial task. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use list_1.index('a') to get 'a' index if there was only one instance of that letter. But as I might see you have duplicate values in your list so for loop should work for that.

```py
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
list_2 = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
indexes = []
search_value = 'a'
for e, value in enumerate(list_1):  # e is basically our counter here so we use it later to find current position index
if value == search_value:
    indexes.append(e)
    
if len(indexes) > 0:  # check if our indexes list is not empty
    for index in indexes:
       list_2[index] = search_value
    
print(list_2)
```

Which will result in :

```py
['a', '2', '3', 'a', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the desired output would be this: `['a', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']`. So I would code it something like this:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']

list_2 = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']


def replace_symbol(list_1, list_2, symbol):
    symbol_to_replace = list_1.index(symbol)
    list_2[symbol_to_replace] = symbol
    print(list_2)  # prints ['a', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
    return list_2


replace_symbol(list_1, list_2, 'a')  # pass the symbol to replace in the function call
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of any value with [`<sequence>.index(<value>)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations).

This "index code" finds the desired item in the first list and in `list_2` inserts this same item using the index just found:

```py
list_1 = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
list_2 = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']

item = 'a'
item_index = list_1.index(item)
list_2.insert(item_index, item)

print(list_1)
print(list_2)
```

In the example above, the output is this:

```
['b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
['1', '2', 'a', '3', '1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
def replace_el(l1, l2, el):
    try:
        l2[l1.index(el)] = el
    except ValueError:
        pass

list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
list_2 = ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']

replace_el(list_1, list_2, 'k')
print(list_2)
replace_el(list_1, list_2, 'a')
print(list_2)
```

And this is the output:

```sh
['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
['a', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
```

The function `replace_el` replaces the element of `l2` in the same position of `el` in `l1`. If `el` is not in `l1`, `l2` is unchanged.